# How much weight should I be able to add to my routine monthly.

Tags: weights

I'm guessing you progress at different levels for different exercise, but as a (very) general rule of thumb, would it be reasonable to add 10lbs a month with bench presses, and maybe more like 20 with squats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the rule of thumb here is a dangerous guide.

Why, because it may work for one or two iterations, but by the third iteration if you have added 60lbs to your squats in 3 months it may be way too much.

This is something you need to listen to what your body is telling you and also a trainer.